# How to construct a counterexample for the reduction of linear second order PDE in several variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In standard PDE textbook, we can find the following result. For the following linear second order partial differential equation 
$$ \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(x)u_{x_ix_j}+\sum_{i=1}^n b_i(x)u_{x_i}+c(x)u(x)=f(x), x\in\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n,$$
it is possible to construct a global $C^2$ transformation to reduce it to canonical form, if the coefficients $a_{ij}, b_i, c$ are only constants.

It is impossible to construct a **global** transformation to reduce the above PDE, if the coefficients $a_{ij}, b_i, c$ are not all constant functions.  But I can not find a counterexample.

Can anyone help me to construct a simple counterexample, or tell me where I can find the counterexample.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which book you are reading, but I think if you know the reason for this result, you don't need counterexamples to help you understand.

Actually, if $u\in C^1$, the given PDE could be transformed to the divergence form. Then you can multiply a $v \in C^{\infty}_0$ to change this equation to its weak form. After that, you may use your bilinear form knowledge to find the coordinate transformation $P$ which could change this PDE to diagonal matrix, and meantime you get $P \nabla u$. If $P$ could pass though $\nabla$, then you can find the canonical form, otherwise, you can't do that.

Obviously, if the coefficients are constant, $P$ would be a scalar matrix which would freely pass through $\nabla$.

I don't know if you understand what I mean. My English might be not good  enough to express it.

Comment: I understand what you mean. According to what you have said, is it possible to reduce the PDE
$$a(x,y,z)u_{xx}+b(x,y,z)u_{yy}+c(x,y,z)u_{zz}=0, b^2-4ac>0, x^2+y^2+z^2<1$$ to canonical form, that is the form of
$$u_{\xi\xi}+(-1)^m u_{\eta\eta}+(-1)^nu_{\zeta\zeta}=0 ?$$
Here $m,n$ are positive integers.